# If someone adapts CC BY-SA content by remixing/building upon it with content that cannot be licensed under a compatible license, who can take action?

Tags: creative-commons, attribution

In a situation, Author A creates content and makes it available under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). Author B takes Author's A content and properly gives them attribution. However, they take content from Author C as well. Author B has the permission to use the content, but it is not CC BY-SA or [a compatible license](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses/) and Author B cannot relicense or sublicense it.

If Author B does not have the right to include Author C's work in a CC BY-SA or compatibly-licensed work product, who can take action against Author B? Can Author A take action, because the terms of the license require adapted work be licensed in a way that is not possible? Or must Author C take action because their work is the one being used in a manner inconsistent with its license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it all depends on what B does.

If B makes their work available under CC BY-SA 4.0, then C can take action against them because now B is distributing C's content or work derived thereof in a manner that C has not consented to.

If B distributes their work not under CC BY-SA 4.0, then A can take against against them for breaching the license under which B has received A's work.

Comment: And in the case where the license of the adaptation is not explicit, I would suspect that A could take action, since the license must be clearly and unambiguously stated.